# right triangles and double angles

Tags: trigonometry

Some right triangles with integer sides e.g. $(3,4,5)$ and $(7,24,25)$ have the property that if the smaller acute angle in the first triangle is $\alpha$ then one of acute angles in the second triangle is $2\alpha$. Is it possible to characterize all pairs of Pythagorean triples with this property?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4324785/right-triangles-and-double-angles) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Off the cuff, I'd say every triple has a triple with which it shares this property.  Start with a triple $(a, b, c)$, with $a^2+b^2 = c^2$.  Then the double angle sine formula says that we need a triple $(b^2-a^2, 2ab, a^2+b^2)$, which is the usual generator for triples.  ETA: Is that enough of a hint, or should I write it out more fully?

Comment: (I should've added $a < b < c$, btw.)